# Program not responding on build visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

First question here, so sorry if my formatting is a bit off.

I'm trying to write a code involving greatest common divisor in c++ as part of a homework assignment. However, whenever I go to build my code, I immediately get a "program is not responding" message. I've tried a basic Hello World code and it compiled fine. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == a) return a;
    else return gcd(b, a%b);
}

int main()
{
    gcd(25,10);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried many different values in calling gcd, but almost all seem to give me the same error. It seems to happen when calling the outside function in main, whenever the "else" line of code is used. I really don't know what to make of it. Am I missing something simple? Thanks.

Comment: Try to add recursive gcd function exit strategy. The function causes heap error I think. Add if param <= 0 then return ... clause.

Comment: Sounds like you have an infinite loop. Inside your `gcd` function, print out the values of `a` and `b` and you'll soon see where it's going wrong.

Comment: This produces a loud bang in VS2013, certainly not a "program is not responding" message.  Do start with the standard Hello World program first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call with 25,10:

- Not equal, call with 10, 5
- Not equal, call with 5, 0
- Still not equal, calculate 5%0   <- something modulo 0

Modulo (division) with 0 isn´t possible (without going into high-level math stuff,
something the CPU won´t do). You can check the crash in your debugger, it should
print more helpful information than the standard windows message.

Simple solution: Check if b is 0 with a `if` before.

Comment: Ah jeez.. Yeah I see it. I guess I shouldn't just trust my professors code snippets. That fixed it perfectly, thank you.